# Minecraft server not loading server.properties when it's loaded as a service

Tags: server, java, configuration, minecraft

I've followed many tutorials, but for some reason the service for my minecraft server won't read the server.properties file. I have a basic understanding of Ubuntu (had to learn how to use it for personal projects and college).

However, when I start it normally through the command line with the following command `java -Xms4G -Xmx12G -jar serverstarter-2.0.1.jar nogui` it does read the server properties file. I already checked if any other server.properties files exist on the system, and as far as I am aware there is only one on the system.

Is this a problem related to screen, or is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

My minecraft@.service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server: %i
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft-servers/%i

User=minecraft
Group=minecraft

ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectControlGroups=true


Restart=always

ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -DmS mc-%i /usr/bin/java -Xms4G -Xmx12G -jar serverstarter-2.0.1.jar nogui
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "say SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 5 SECONDS. SAVING ALL MAPS..."\015'
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "save-all"\015'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "stop"\015'


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If there's any other data needed I'll be happy to provide it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the server properties file and is it accessible by the `minecraft` user account? 

Comment: @matigo Yeah, it is accessible. It's owned by the minecraft user account, the entire server folder is. I start the server with the java command on the minecraft account as well, and it has no problems loading server.properties when I do it that way instead of the systemctl start minecraft@ishikawa-aof3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you manually starting minecraft with the same user / group as in the service definition?

If you are, I would guess it's looking for server.properties in the wrong directory.

In your ExecStart, try adding a script that does the screen setup, but first changes dir to the correct dir where server.properties is located.

I have a few minecraft servers that I start from crontab @reboot.

/usr/bin/screen -dmS vanillamc /home/xxxx/minecraft/minecraft-1.17.sh

My script (you can adapt and send your dynamic working dir as input)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/xxxx/minecraft/

MEM="-Xms1G -Xmx2G"

JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin/java

$JAVA $MEM -jar minecraft_server-1.17.jar nogui
```

Comment: I tried this with the following code: ```#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/minecraft-servers/ishikawa-aof3/
MEM="-Xms4G -Xmx12G"
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
$JAVA $MEM -jar serverstarter-2.0.1.jar nogui
``` and it errored when I tried starting the service. However, when I start the script normally with sudo start.sh it did launch the server.

Comment: EDIT: I tried again and it seems to work now. Gonna reboot the server and hope that it still works and loads the server config. Note: **I just tried it and it doesn't load the config. Both not normally, and upon reboot.**

Comment: **UPDATE:** I'm not exactly sure what I changed, but it seems to be working now. Will have to further test it once I'm home, thank you for the help!